# How to write a query in to get multiple rows from 3 different tables using MAX() in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables as follows:

**Table 1**

```
Id1  Id2    Value
---------------
001   200    wm2  
002   200    wm3  
003   200    NULL
```

**Table 2**

```
Id1 Id3 Version
-------------------
001 3001  1  
001 3002   2  
002 4001   1  
002 4002   2
```

**Table 3**

```
Id3 Value 1 Value Value 2
-------------------------
3001 Test 1  Hellow How are you?  
3002 Test 1  Hello How are you?  
4001 Test 2 how can i help you?  
4002 Test 2 How can I help you?
```

I need the output as follows :

```
Id3 Value 1 Value Value 2
-------------------
3002 Test 1 wm2 Hello How are you?
4002 Test 2 wms3 How can I help you?
```

I have to write in SQL Server and I am trying to use `MAX()` for table 2 but not able to get the right output.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to use MAX()?

Comment: I think they are using max on Id3 for the join from table2 to table1 @TabAlleman but definitely confusing

Comment: to query in table 2 for the max value for Version? But i am open for other suggestions

Comment: What does Table 1 even have to do with the desired result?

Comment: What logic are you using to get such an output?

Comment: The sample data doesn't seem to match your stated desired output. And even if it did this doesn't make much sense. How do you know which row from Table3 is the row you want?

Comment: Looks like an intermediate step in a learning assignment to me. Filtering on Table1 by `t1.value is not null`, and I bet the `MAX()` should be on `Version`, not the `ID3` field.  I could be wrong, but this would show how to use `MAX()` on an intermediate table where the data wanted is not the data you are using `MAX()` on, like finding a value from the last date recorded.

Comment: @SeanLange - Output is now matching. Thanks for highlighting it.

Comment: the reason to 2 all 3 tables is from table 1 I can first 2 records where there is data in Value column and then those Id1s I am querying in table 2 to latest Version and corresponding Id3 and then I have to use that output in Table to get the desired result.

Comment: @AmitJ Why Table 2 and Table 3 are two different tables and not one table with all the columns. Also, in that case you can query data from one table, and there is no need for Table 1 as no condition to check from Table 1 columns beside Id1, which is already there in Table 2

Comment: @AmitJ Well, you can have Id1 |  Id3 | Version | Value1 | Value2 in one table only and there is no need for Table 1

Comment: @SonalBorkar - This is how they are created in DB. I cannot change them now.

Comment: @AmitJ Please see below my answer

Answer (score 2):

Does this even need `Table2` (or `Table1`)? This *would* achieve the result you want, and doesn't need any data from the other 2 tables:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
       ID3,
       Value1,
       Value2
FROM Table3
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Value1 ORDER BY ID3 DESC);
```

Comment: How would this return that output? There isn't even any data to return what he wants.

Comment: Both of our answers return the same, which is what the OP stated the expected output is @CetinBasoz

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at @CetinBasoz , the OP has provided both sample data and expected results.

Comment: The OP originally had bad data posted in the question. The desired output did not match the data. They have since fixed that and this works just like scsimon's. I would choose this method as it simpler but this doesn't work in outdated systems like 2008.

Comment: I love `with ties` but for some reason (granted i haven't put in the time to research) it performs terribly compared to my answer, or using `row_number` in a cte or derived table. No idea why...

Comment: OK OP edited the output and now it matches, but it doesn't match to the explanation. It has relation to table1 which doesn't exist in your query.

Comment: @SeanLange one would *hope* that the OP isn't using such an outdated version. :)

Comment: LOL same here but we see it over and over around here.

Comment: It's when you see 2005 (and prior) that there's a real concern @SeanLange. And they're far from infrequent either. :(

Comment: @Larnu - I forgot to add 1 column in the output. I have added the same now. Please check I guess for this i need to have Table 1 and Table 2.

Comment: @AmitJ considering that's a column in `Table3` you should be more than capable of adding it to the `SELECT` clause. You need to understand what it's doing and adding an extra column isn't affectimg that.

Answer (score 1):

One way is a self join to a derived table

```
select
    table3.*
from table3
inner join 
    table2 on table2.Id3 = table3.Id3
inner join
    (select Id3 = max(Id3), Id1 from table2 group by Id1) t22
    on t22.Id3 = table2.Id3 and t22.Id1 = table2.Id1
```

Comment: There isn't data to return what he wants. This would only return a result as the other answer.

Comment: I do t understand what you mean.

Comment: Just try your query and check the result against OP's desired output (not clear how OP could even find such an output). For example your result would lack "Hello, Hello How are you?" for Value2.

Comment: Check this DBFiddle demo. Both answers return the same thing and that is not what OP wants: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e869aab6eb42e0094be464218672ec5

Comment: Yeah well this looks pretty spot on to me...https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d9acf922b1dc03885cf389bf53775eea that's exactly what is in the expected output.  I don't see how you don't see that they match....

Comment: @CetinBasoz your fiddle returns exactly what the OP stated for both this answer and the one from Larnu. The OP originally had bad data posted in the question.

Comment: @SeanLange, no I meant, I created that DBFiddle to show both answers were returning different data than the one answers provided. Later OP edited the output. Now answers do not match to do explanation (Table1.Value should not be null). Check my answer to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want:

```
select * from table3 t3
where id3 in
(
  select max(Id3)
  from Table1 t1
  inner join Table2 t2 on t1.Id1 = t2.Id1
  where [Value] is not null
  group by t1.id1
);
```

Comment: How is this any different to the answers from myself and scsimon's answers, when you claim on both of them that *"There isn't even any data to return what he wants."*?

Comment: @Larnu, the output is coincidentally same. Read what OP wants.

Comment: I re-read the question and your comment still doesn't make sense to me. We could join in table1 but it's not needed. I could join in a bunch of random tables that wouldn't affect the answer... but why?

Comment: The difference is that originally Table1 seems irrelevant but since the OP updated the data it is used in the join and will only return rows where Table1.Value is not null. But that is an assumption implied with this answer. Not saying it is correct or incorrect. It is indeterminate because the OP has not clarified that subtlety.

Comment: @scsimon, of course needed. Read carefully, he explicitly says "..  from table 1 I can first 2 records where there is data in Value column and then those Id1s I am querying in table 2..."

Comment: Sigh....hiding requirements in the comments is not good. But the OP is new so probably doesn't realize that. Would have been a lot clearer from you if instead of just saying the other were wrong you explained why. I agree now that Table1 need to be included but we sure got there the long way.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below query:

```
SELECT a.Id3, a.Value1, a.Value2 from Table3 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.Id3 = b.Id3
WHERE b.Id1 IN
 (select Id1 from Table1 where Value IS NOT NULL)
AND b.Version = (Select MAX(Version) from Table2 c where c.Id3 = b.Id3)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Sonal, I forgot to add 1 column in the output. Update the output. Please check